# TwitterOAuth - Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to make PHP application with Twitter OAuth. In my code I used [twitteroauth](https://twitteroauth.com/) library. I was trying to make authorization like in library tutorial but I when I try make request token I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'Failed to validate oauth signature and token' in /home/kp/domains/konradprzydzial.pl/public_html/tweetupchat/vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:221 Stack trace: #0 /home/kp/domains/konradprzydzial.pl/public_html/tweetupchat/login.php(10): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/request_t...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/kp/domains/konradprzydzial.pl/public_html/tweetupchat/vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 221

My code in this file:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";
require "config.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

var_dump($request_token['oauth_token']);
var_dump($request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));

echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Zaloguj się</a>';

?>
```

CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET are correct. Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you dumped the consumer values right before the object instantiation just to double check they are correct? Also, is your computer's system clock set correctly? Twitter will fail if your >~5 minutes out of sync.

Comment: I dumped it and it is correct.
I use shared hosting. Server time is 2 minutes ahead than time in Twitter API status.

Answer (score 2):

I am also using the abraham/twitteroauth wrapper for the twitter API and ran into the same problem.

The code you have here looks good. However, if you were using the documentation that was given by abraham on https://twitteroauth.com/redirect.php, then one solution is to remove the `getenv()` function around the `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET`.

I can only speculate as I do not know the code used in your config.php file, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the CURL problem
try check if they passing the right parameter

> abraham\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php at line 348

```
function request($url, $method, $headers, $postfields)
```